# What is dereferenced error?

Tags: java

I executed the following code and I got the following errors.
I make some edit for last part in order to make it in code format.
RunUnitConvert.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
* 
*  This is a test driver for the UnitConverter class
*  Write a unit conversion program that asks users to 
*  identify the unit from which they want to convert and 
*  the unit to which they want to convert. Legal units 
*  are in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, and km. Define two 
*  objects of a class UnitConverter that convert 
*  between meters and a given unit.
*  
*/
public class RunUnitConverter
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
           BufferedReader br;
           char fromUnit = '\0';
           char toUnit = '\0';
           double value = 0;

    //  prompt the user to enter unit to convert from
        System.out.print("Convert from: ");
    //  open up standard input
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));    
        try {
            fromUnit = (char)br.read();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {         
            System.exit(1);
        }
    // prompt user to enter unit to convert to
        System.out.print("Convert to: ");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            toUnit = (char)br.read();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.exit(1);     
    }

    // create new UnitConvert objects
         UnitConverter from = new UnitConverter(fromUnit);
        UnitConverter to = new UnitConverter(toUnit);

    // prompt user to enter initial value to convert
        System.out.print("Value: ");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            value = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.exit(1);     
        }

        double metric = from.toMetric(value);
        double converted = to.fromMetric(metric);

        if (converted < 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Bad Input");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(value + " " + fromUnit + " = " + converted +    " " + toUnit);
        }
    }
}
```

UnitConvert.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
* 
 *  This is a test driver for the UnitConverter class
*  Write a unit conversion program that asks users to 
*  identify the unit from which they want to convert and 
*  the unit to which they want to convert. Legal units 
*  are in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, and km. Define two 
*  objects of a class UnitConverter that convert 
*  between meters and a given unit.
*  
*/
public class RunUnitConverter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedReader br;
        char fromUnit = '\0';
        char toUnit = '\0';
    double value = 0;

    //  prompt the user to enter unit to convert from
        System.out.print("Convert from: ");
    //  open up standard input
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));    
        try {
            fromUnit = (char)br.read();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {         
            System.exit(1);
        }
    // prompt user to enter unit to convert to
        System.out.print("Convert to: ");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            toUnit = (char)br.read();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.exit(1);     
        }

    // create new UnitConvert objects
        UnitConverter from = new UnitConverter(fromUnit);
        UnitConverter to = new UnitConverter(toUnit);

    // prompt user to enter initial value to convert
        System.out.print("Value: ");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            value = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.exit(1);     
       }

        double metric = from.toMetric(value);
       double converted = to.fromMetric(metric);

        if (converted < 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Bad Input");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println(value + " " + fromUnit + " = " + converted + " " + toUnit);
     }
    }
}
```

This is the errors that I have
The output and error were the following:
javac RunUnitConverter.java
 char cannot be dereferenced
switch (strUnit.charAt(0)){
                           ^
char cannot be dereferenced
 switch (strUnit.charAt(0)){
                           ^
2 errors

Comment: Well, the problem is clearly in `UnitConverter` - but you haven't posted that. It looks like `strUnit` is a `char` variable, but you probably intended it to be a `String` variable.

Comment: Take a look please for the edition version if you still have a time

Comment: You haven't included any code which contains `strUnit`. Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (Hint: it probably doesn't need nearly as much code as you *have* posted, and I suspect that in trying to reproduce it you'll find the error...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is exactly as the error message says. "strUnit" is of type char, it is not an Object, and thus has no methods.

Comment: What should I do then ?